# How to lower accuracy db.GeoPtProperty to 2 decimals

Tags: django, google-app-engine

GeoPtProperty like

```
{{a.geopt.lat}}
```

and heuristically found 2 decimals get "good enough" for my requirements. So I try to round off to 2 decimals either with template filter like a django filter or by python code. Can you recommend a how to proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Django template docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) seem to indicate that you can round in the template with `{{a.geopt.lat|floatformat:2}}`

I've never tried it before, give it a shot.